# Which timezone does Puppeteer configure Chromium for?

Tags: timezone, chromium, puppeteer

Using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) 0.13.0, I'm wondering which timezone it configures its Chromium instances for?

It appears to me, from my testing, that Chromium will use UTC for timezone, but I can't find any confirmation of this anywhere.

For example, if I log the current time, via `console.log(new Date())` in the Puppeteer Chromium instance, I get UTC time: `Wed Jan 10 2018 08:10:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)`. If I do the same in my normal Chrome browser however, I get local time: `Wed Jan 10 2018 09:09:36 GMT+0100 (CET)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if this problem is solved as of Puppeteer 1.0, so I guess it was a bug.